# Convert string to array then sum error for pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following table

| userid | eventid | urlclick |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | EID-1 | 0,0,0,0,0 |
| A | EID-1 | 0,1,2,3,0 |
| A | EID-1 | 0,1,0,1,0 |
| A | EID-2 | 1,0,0,0,0 |
| A | EID-2 | 0,0,2,4,1 |
| A | EID-2 | 0,0,0,1,0 |

I was able to convert the urlclick column to np.array with this code

```
time.urlclick = time['urlclick'].apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(x)))
```

Now I want to group the table by event id and sum the urlclikc with axis = 0

```
time.groupby(['userid','eventid']).urlclick.apply(np.array).sum(axis = 0)
```

So that the result should be

```
EID-1 - 0,2,2,4,0
EID-2 - 1,0,2,5,1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time.groupby(['userid','eventid']).urlclick.apply(lambda x: x.sum(axis = 0))
```